# WITH SQL Query gives error when constraining on WITH Table's column

Tags: sql, oracle, select, greatest-n-per-group, common-table-expression

What's wrong with this query? **(Oracle)**

```
with latestplans as (
    select plan_id, max(plan_last_changed_date) 
    from idp.trainee_search_vw 
    group by plan_id 
)
select plan_id, training_organization 
from idp.trainee_search_vw 
where plan_id in (latestplans.plan_id);
```

The error is:

> ORA-00904: `"LATESTPLANS"."PLAN_ID": invalid identifier`

I am defining a temp table which contains a column from view and another column with a Max-grouping. Then, I need to select on that temp table's column.

The goal is to select certain attributes for the latest Plans only, whereas the View originally lists all Plans.

The inner query works.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `select`:

```
plan_id in (select latestplans.plan_id from latestplans);
```

CTEs behave like table or view names.  You can't just use them without referencing them in a `from` clause.

Answer (score 1):

In your query you missed reference of `latestplans` with your  view `trainee_search_vw`.

```
with latestplans as 
  (    select plan_id, max(plan_last_changed_date) from idp.trainee_search_vw 
group by plan_id )
select plan_id, training_organization 
from idp.trainee_search_vw as vw 
where exists (select 1 from latestplans where vw.plan_id=latestplans.plan_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

It has ben explained already what the problem is with the way you use the CTE.

Let me pinpoing, however, that:

- your query does not seem to do what you describe: the outer query should be filtering on the maximum date rather than on the `plan_id`; as it is, the query returns all rows of the table
- you don't need to scan the table twice to get the result that you want; you could solve this greatest-n-per-group problem with window functions

Query:

```
select plan_id, training_organization
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by plan_id order by plan_last_changed_date desc) rn
    from idp.trainee_search_vw t
) t
where rn = 1
```

You could also use aggregation and Oracle's `keep` syntax:

```
select 
    plan_id, 
    max(training_organization) 
        keep(dense_rank first order by plan_last_changed_date desc) training_organization
from idp.trainee_search_vw
group by plan_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with latestplans as 
  (    select plan_id, max(plan_last_changed_date) max-plan_date
       from idp.trainee_search_vw 
       group by plan_id
   )

 select vw.plan_id, vw.training_organization,lp.max_plan_date
  from idp.trainee_search_vw vw
   Inner join  latestplans lp on lp.plan_id=vw.plan_id
```

Also, You can use where after join